# Java JTable function for loading an Object

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtabbedpane

I have a jtable in an java application and it reads an object[x][y] when created (with the jtablejTable3.setModel() function).Is there any function when objects data be changed to load them in my java table

Answer (score 0):

put your data in the tablemodel, and call

```
tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the repaid() function? 
I tried it but didnt worked for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`EventTableModel`](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/swing/EventTableModel.html) from the Glazed Lists library to back your `JTable`.